# How can i call javascript function from backend within updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

How can I call javascript function from backend within updatepanel in asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,yourUpdatePanel.getType(),"Your js",true);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its not hard to do, but it's depends on you, how you can call a method/function,

1) without update panel

```js
function welcome() 
{
alert("Welcome Guys!");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "OnLoad", "welcome();", true);
}
```

2) With update panel

```js
function welcome() 
{
alert("Welcome Guys!");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JsStatus","welcome();", true);
}
```

both are perfectly works ;)